# CBIR average rank functions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cbir

Here is my codes for computing the average rank for each image from 1000 images. (We assume every 100 images are one catagory, e.g, 1-100, 101-200,....)

```
for z=1:1000
H{z}=imread(strcat(int2str(z-1),'.jpg'));

Im_red=H{z}(:,:,1);
Im_green= H{z}(:,:,2);
Im_blue= H{z}(:,:,3);
hist_im1=zeros(1,256); 
[h,w]=size(Im_red); 
for i=1:h   
for j=1:w
value_pixel1=Im_red(i,j)+1;
hist_im1(value_pixel1)=hist_im1(value_pixel1)+1;
end
end
hist_im2=zeros(1,256); 
[h,w]=size(Im_green); 
for i=1:h   
for j=1:w
value_pixel2=Im_green(i,j)+1;
hist_im2(value_pixel2)=hist_im2(value_pixel2)+1;
end
end
hist_im3=zeros(1,256); 
[h,w]=size(Im_blue); 
for i=1:h   
for j=1:w
value_pixel3 = Im_blue(i,j) + 1;
hist_im3(value_pixel3) = hist_im3(value_pixel3)+1;
end
end
Q{z}=[hist_im1, hist_im2, hist_im3];
end

for r=1:1000
for i=1:1000
a(r,i)=matchfunction(Q{r},Q{i});
end

for j=1:1000
b(r,j)=j;
end

L=[a;b];
end
for r=1:1000
B=[L(r,:);L(r+1000,:)];

[d1,d2] = sort(B(1,:),'descend');
C=B(:,d2);

aaa=C(1,:);
bbb=C(2,:);
ccc=zeros(1,1000);

for g=1:1000
if ((bbb(g)>=fix((r-1)/100)*100+1) & (bbb(g)<=ceil(r/100)*100))
ccc(g)=g;
end

end

ddd=sum(ccc(g))/100;

s(r)=ddd

end

avgrank(1)=sum(s(1:100))/100
avgrank(2)=sum(s(101:200))/100
avgrank(3)=sum(s(201:300))/100
avgrank(4)=sum(s(301:400))/100
avgrank(5)=sum(s(401:500))/100
avgrank(6)=sum(s(501:600))/100
avgrank(7)=sum(s(601:700))/100
avgrank(8)=sum(s(701:800))/100
avgrank(9)=sum(s(801:900))/100
avgrank(10)=sum(s(901:1000))/100
xCoordinates = 1:10;
plot(xCoordinates,avgrank,'b:*');
```

The match function is a function computes the match value of two histograms of two images with two histograms as input. You can see that `Q{z}` is the histogram. I think my problem is within here:

```
for g=1:1000
if ((bbb(g)>=fix((r-1)/100)*100+1) & (bbb(g)<=ceil(r/100)*100))
ccc(g)=g;
end

end
```

This is how I calculate the rank. So I just give the rank to `ccc(g)`

since for `g` runs from 1 to 1000, it will just be the rank we nee if we have

```
(bbb(g)>=fix((r-1)/100)*100+1) & (bbb(g)<=ceil(r/100)*100)
```

for a `g`. 
But why after I run this program I got the value of `ccc` is one thousand 0s? Why 0? Is there anything wrong with my way of getting the rank through `ccc`? And is there more errors of my code? I just get the average ranks and the `ccc` all 0 but cannot figure out why. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does first 3 loops of `i,j` do?

Comment: @Kamtal, that's for computing the histogram from each channel, red, green, blue

Comment: Why not use `imhist`?

Comment: @Kamtal, I just did not, did some programming practice

Comment: @Kamtal, any comment for my problems?

Comment: @Kamtal, No. `r` ranges from 1 to 1000 while `fix((r-1)/100)*100+1)` does not

Comment: @Kamtal, the if condition is to judge if the image retrieved belongs to its catagory. If yes, we count the rank--that's we i did for `ccc` and what i said about my problem.